# Indexed Sets, a notation question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, index-notation

Consider a collection of sets $B=\{A_i: i\in \mathbb{N}\}$ and assume I want to work with some some set in this collection that satisfies property $P$. Assume also that at least one set in $B$ has property $P$.

Which of the following is appropriate?

- Choose some $A_i \in B$ such that $P$ holds.
- Choose some $A_j \in B$ such that $P$ holds.

The first option re-uses the indexing variable $i$. Is this allowed? Is this conveying that I am working with any element in the collection satisfying property $P$ without fixing which set I am working with exactly?

The second option introduces a new indexing variable $j$. Is this appropriate since it tells the reader that I am fixing a specific $j\in\mathbb{N}$ and am now working with the fixed set $A_j$. (Though all that is known about $A_j$ is that is an element of $B$ satisfying property $P$.

I have seen this done multiple ways and it is always clear what is being conveyed. My goal is to figure out what, if anything, is an abuse of notation, and what is technically correct. Also, I want to know any implications of re-using the index variable. I am looking for more than just "You interpret both statements the same" unless there is a formal reason for it (perhaps referencing the logic notion of variable substitution). Finally, if my notion of what it means to "fix" a set with a given property when multiple such sets may exist is not well-defined, please elaborate on that idea.

Comment: Reusing the indexing variable is technically fine but potentially ambiguous and confusing and I think introducing a second variable is better. The first use of it is "scoped" but it's still confusing.

Comment: Standard mathematical writing isn't particularly formal or precise with regard to things like this, so I'm not sure you'll get the precise answer you're hoping for. But I'd say both versions are the same because both introduce a new symbol distinct from the $i$ that was used when defining $B$, which is now "out of scope" and can't be referenced.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I just want to thank you for all the questions, answers, and comments you have made on MSE and MO over the years. Time and time again, I have come across something written by you and found it extremely insightful. I imagine so many others have as well. I wish someone out there would pay you loads of money to write math textbooks, since you are obviously very gifted at absorbing/consolidating massive amounts of mathematics and conveying it in a clear, motivated way.

Comment: @Mithrandir: thank you very much! As it happens I've been daydreaming about writing a book about linear algebra...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Consider this an intent to pre-order! I'd be especially interested in a linear algebra textbook that approached topics from the perspective of category theory.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I had in mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preferences vary from individual to individual, hence there can be no Single Correct Answer.**

**Having said that , these are my thoughts on this situation :**

**(A)** In "Choose some $A_i \in B$ with $P$" , it is reusing the Index $i$ which is correct , but we might confuse that with the earlier $i$.

**(B)** In "Choose some $A_j \in B$ with $P$" , it is not reusing the Index which is also correct , but we have no information about $j$ , whether it is Even or ODD or Single Digit.

**Consider these 3 alternatives :**

**(C)** "Choose some $C \in B$ with $P(C)$" where there is no reuse of Index & there is no Index at all !
Your Question : "Is this conveying that I am working with any element in the collection satisfying property P without fixing which set I am working with exactly?"
This is the Exact thing that this is conveying !

**(D)** "Choose some $i \in N$ such that [ $A_i \in B$ with ] $P(A_i)$" [ the Part in Brackets in redundant but adds clarity & can be removed ]
In this case, you can (re-)use which-ever Index variable you want , because you are (re-)introducing it & again saying that it is in $N$ (You can change this to Even or ODD or Single Digit suitable to use in your context).

**(E)** "Let $E=\{ U : (U \in B) \land P(U) \}$ , Choose some $V \in E$"
Here too , we are not concentrating on the Index & more-over we are having the Possibility that there are multiple elements with the Property $P$. We might use Set E when we want to make a general Statement about $V$ or we might Prove that Set E is a Singleton.

**Thoughts about "Scope" of the Index :**

In $U+\sum_{i=1}^{i=N}{(i+V)}$ , the Index is $i$ & we can use that only here , because it is in "Scope" whereas $N$ , $U$ & $V$ are not limited.
The same thing occurs in the Index Set Case, where earlier $i$ is limited to the earlier "Scope" & the next $i$ is limited to the next "Scope".
**Why we should avoid that :**
(1) When we re-use the Index , we are making it a little harder to see the whole , & we are introducing unnecessary (avoidable) confusion.
(2) Unlike Computer Programming , there is no Compiler error when we use out-of-scope variable or Index. We can still reach in later, to state (eg) that $i$ must be between $100$ & $1000$ , then it is ambiguous which $i$ we are talking about. When use use $i$ & $j$ , that ambiguity will not occur.
**Why we should still use that :**
It is a very "Common Practice" to use & reuse Index variable $i$ , while making sure that we are not mixing the various Instances or making unnecessary ambiguity.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed discussion and clarifying examples. I am considering accepting this answer but would really like to see some explicit reference to the notion of variable scope which was mentioned in Qiaochu and Karl's comments. Variable scoping, now that I have encountered the term, seems to be the heart of what my question is about.